# See if mouse click was handled

Tags: c++, mouse

I'm currently making a whimsical iPhone app that will allow you to change your windows cursor into a space ship controlled by the iPhone (simple rotation and such), and currently I have the movement and clicking handled, however I'd like to add additional features, such as bullets that you can shoot around the screen which will move until they die or hit a button, which will then be clicked. And I have two questions:

**Question number one:** Is there *any* way to detect if the mouse is currently over some click-able button? OR is there any way to see if a mouse event *was* handled?

**Question number two:** Is there any way to overlay the screen with small bullets? (perhaps small [3,3] child windows or something?)

**Further Information:**
The client program will be in c++
SDL or SFML will likely be the graphics libs, if any are necessary (winAPI should be fine)

Comment: WinAPI for the program that receives input from the iPhone on the computer =]    
iPhone == Obj-C and all frameworks involved! I'm sorry for not pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most reliable route would be the [Microsoft Active Accessibility interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd373592.aspx). Many tools to help visually impaired people need to answer the question "Is this a button?", and MSAA answers that question.

Overlaying the screen is trvial in a Windows environment; just create a window :). It can be partially transparent, so you're not restricted to rectangular bullets.